# What error handling should be used in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, error-handling

What error handling should be used in VB.NET?

Should one use the "`On Error Goto ErrorHandler ... Exit Sub ErrHandler ... End Sub`" pattern or should you use the "`try { ... } catch { ... } finally { ... }`" pattern?

Comment: And if you even think of using "On Error Resume Next" I'm afraid that we'd have to put you down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most obvious reasons I can think of off the top of my head to steer clear of `On Error GoTo...` would have to be:

1. `On Error GoTo` does not discriminate between *types* of exceptions.
2. `On Error GoTo` does not provide as much structure as `Try`/`Catch`/`Finally` (e.g., nesting one `Try`/`Catch` block within another).
3. `On Error GoTo` has no counterpart to `Finally` (that I know of).

I'm sure in many cases, clever use of `On Error GoTo` could mimic the behavior that is built in to VB.NET's `Try`/`Catch`/`Finally` feature. But what would be the point?

Answer (score 6):

"try { ... } catch { ... } finally { ...}" pattern by a long shot.

```
C#

try
{
// Do Something that may go wrong
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
//Do something with the error
}
finally
{
//Cleanup
}
```

or

```
VB

Try

// Do Something that may go wrong

Catch ex  as Exception

//Do something with the error

Finally

//Cleanup

End Try
```

Comment: lol! This is very true - I was being extremely lazy there and copy and pasted from the OP.  I have edited my answer to include both language examples.

Comment: @barry: why choose the try catch pattern?

Comment: @Craig There are so many reasons why you should use try catch.  I personally find it more logical.  Try doing this section of code, if it fails then catch the exception and carry on if you can.  I find OnError extremely difficult to follow and very messy.  There is nice article on MSDN about life without OnError http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289194(VS.71).aspx

Comment: @Barry: can you refer to the Err object when using "try ... catch" or are you forced to use the Exception object?

Comment: @Craig Johnston: You should be using `Exceptions`, they are much more flexible that the old `Err`.

Comment: @Craig No you use the Exception object.  Although `Exception` should be the very last exception to catch.  You should always list exceptions in order.  So specific execptions come first flowing down to the general `Execpetion` last.  So if you are connecting to SQL you should catch `SQLException` first as this will contain detailed error information specific to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

`On Error Goto ErrorHandler ... Exit Sub ErrHandler ... End Sub` is from the VB6 days. Definitely go with `Try... Catch... Finally...`

Answer (score 0):

A little background

'On Error Goto' is the way things were done in VB 6 before the .Net days. The VB compiler still allows this so you can easily port old VB code to VB.Net. VB.Net is probably the only .Net language that supports this.

'Try Catch Finally' is the .Net way to do things and a lot more flexible allowing you to catch, wrap and rethrow exceptions. It allows for easier interoperation between components written in different languages and is a lot more readable when you do more complex error handling because you don't have goto's.

Answer (score -1):

Old post, but here's my two penneth. Debugging with `On Error Goto` is a lot easier than `Try Catch`:

```
On Error Goto ErrHand
do something that goes wrong
do something else

ErrHand:
Resume Next
```

Place a breakpoint on `Resume Next` and if it hits, step through your code once and you jump to the statement directly after the one that caused the exception, making it a lot easier to track down the problem.

`On Error Goto` is also good if you *expect* errors, like resources that are created by other processes that you are not in control of and aren't yet available, or locked resources when you know other processes will lock a resource and you must wait your turn. With `On Error Goto` you can wait for a bit and then `Resume Retry`, where `Retry` is a label in your code to try the operation again. When you look at code with that structure it's very obvious what's going on:

```
  On Error Goto ErrHand

  dim ErrCnt as Integer = 0
  do something

RetryFile:
  On Error Goto FileErr
  download a file

  On error Goto ErrHand
  do something with the file

  On Error Goto 0
  Goto Done

FileErr:
  ErrCnt += 1

  if ErrCnt < 10 then
    sleep for a while
    Resume RetryFile
  else
    Throw New Exception("Can't download the file")
  end if

ErrHand:
  Throw New Exception(Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description)

Done:
  tidy up
```

One last point. I use both structures as I do like the `Try Catch` nesting, but as can be seen from the above, similar functionality can by achieved with `On Error Goto`, and in some ways it's neater as it moves the error handling out of the flow of the main code and all into one place.